# How to define our own types of errors and handle them explicitly?

Tags: ballerina

I want to have two types of errors, `ClientError`, and `ServiceError`, in my service implementation. They should also be a type of error so that I can throw these errors to the top level and perform a rollback when an error is thrown. Is there a solution for this in Ballerina?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in [error subtyping](https://ballerina.io/learn/by-example/error-subtyping/), you can use a `distinct` error for this scenario.

```
type ClientError distinct error;
type ServiceError distinct error;

// Common type specific to the above two errors
type Error ClientError|ServiceError;
```

Once the errors are defined, you can handle them accordingly as shown below.

```
function throwClientError() returns ClientError {
    return error("some client error");
}

public function main() {
    error err = throwClientError();

    // If needed to handle only these two types of errors
    if (err is Error) {

    }

    // If needed to handle only client errors
    if (err is ClientError) {

    }

    // If needed to handle only service errors
    if (err is ServiceError) {

    }
}
```